# Finding the number of pixels with no value for multiple images

Tags: pixel

I have 677 LANDSAT images and many of them are missing data for some pixels. I am trying to figure out how many pixels have no data for each image (or how many pixels have values for each images) so I can exclude images with less than 30% coverage. My images are in TIFF format.

Comment: You'll have to look for tiff parsers. What language are you working in?

Comment: If in Python check this out: https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/